# Show that every sequence in $l_2 (ℝ)$ is the limit of a sequence in $l_0(ℝ)$.

Tags: analysis

*Consider the real linear space of sequences of real numbers 
$$l_0(ℝ) := \{(a_n)_{n∈ℕ} : a_n ∈ℝ ,a_n≠0 \text{ for finite many $n$} \} $$ and $$l_2(ℝ) := \{(a_n)_{n∈ℕ} : a_n ∈ ℝ, \sum_{n=1}^{∞} {a_n}^2 < ∞ \} $$
Show that every sequence in $l_2 (ℝ)$ is the limit of a sequence in $l_0(ℝ)$.*

I don't understand this. I would think that the limit of a sequence in $l_0(ℝ)$ must be a real number and certainly not a sequence. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I imagine they meant to ask "Show that every element of $\ell_2(\Bbb R)$..."

Comment: Right, they are using 'sequence in $l_k(\Bbb R)$' with two different meanings.

Comment: Limit for which topology?

Comment: @Did I don't know what the word topology means, but limit is defined as:

A sequence $\{v_n \}$ in the innerproduct space $V$ converges to a a vector $V$ if $\lim_{n→ ∞} ||v_n -v|| = 0$. We say that $v$ is the limit of the sequence $\{v_n \}$.

Comment: Do you mean convergence for the $\ell_2$ norm, then?

Comment: @Did I don't try to mean anything. I'm to figure out what is meant :P

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a_n^{(k)} := \{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k, 0, 0, \ldots\} \in l_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n^{(k)}-a_n|^2 = \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty|a_n|^2$.

Comment: I don't really see what I need to prove. So I would begin with take an random sequence  $(a_0,a_1,...) ∈ l_2(ℝ)$. Or do I need to say take an random sequence $(a_0,a_1,...)$ such that $a_i ∈ l_2(ℝ)$.

Comment: You take an element of $l_2$, i.e. a sequence $a_n$ of real numbers with $\sum|a_n|^2 < \infty$ and construct a sequence of elements of $l_0(\mathbb{R}) \subset l_2$, i.e. a sequence of sequences of real numbers, which converges to the element of $l_2$.

Comment: Ah, at least, I understand the question now. I need to go now, I'll look at your hint later. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I understand your hint now. But I'm not sure how to prove (rigoursly) that $\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty|a_n|^2$ will go to zero when $k \to 0$. Do I need to say something like: Assume this wouldn't be zero. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{∞} {a_n}^2 < ∞$ wouldn't hold.

Comment: This is a property of convergent series. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges then $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=k}^\infty x_n = 0$.

Comment: Aaaaah, was thinking for hours if things like $1/n$ could ruin this :P , but this make sense.